# TypeError: Movie() got an unexpected keyword argument 'actors'

Tags: python, django

I am working on a school project using Django and Python.

Now I have created a website for using rest-apis. However, while testing I encountered an error that I simply can't seem to be able to solve. It occurs whenever I try to create a movie with POSTMAN using the api.I get the following error over and over again and I can't find what is wrong.

Error message:

```
raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: Movie() got an unexpected keyword argument 'actors'
```

My serializer

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Queryset gets all the data from the Actor model as specified with objects.all()
    actor_pks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Actor.objects.all(), source='actors', write_only=True,
                                                   label='Actors', many=True)
    rent_pks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='rent', read_only=True, label='Rent')

    # Change image-options to allow post/put/patch without an image
    image = serializers.ImageField(allow_null=True, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get additional parameters from constructor
        depth = kwargs.pop('depth', None)
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Add diffrent pks to fields if field is not None from constructor
        fields.append('actor_pks') if fields is not None else None
        fields.append('rent_pks') if fields is not None else None
        fields.append('image') if fields is not None else None

        # Overwrite meta tags
        self.Meta.depth = depth if depth is not None else 1
        self.Meta.fields = fields if fields is not None else '__all__'

        # Call super-constructor
        super(MovieSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
```

My Movie Model:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    """
    Movie-Model. Many-to-Many relation with Rent.
    """
    title = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=50)
    publishdate = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=20)
    genre = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
    is_borrowed = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, upload_to='movies', default='noimage.png')
    rent = models.ManyToManyField(Rent, blank=False)
    actor = models.ForeignKey(Actor, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.image:
            if self.id:
                self.image = Movie.objects.get(pk=self.id).image
            else:
                self.image = 'noimage.png'
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I would be glad for any help with this problem. I have been working on it quite a while now and I am simply to dumb to find a solution for this.

Thanks for your help lads.

Comment: `Movie` has no `actors` field, only an `actor`...

Comment: I changed that. Got another Error instead saying the following:
ValueError: Cannot assign "[<Actor: Luke Skywalker>]": "Movie.actors" must be a "Actor" instance.

I am a real noob when it comes to Django and Python in general. And once again I have no clue where to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of time I was able to find the the answer to the question.

In the models in my Movie model, I had the following field implemented.

```
 actor = models.ForeignKey(Actor, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Turns out I had it's relation set wrong and therefor the serializer threw the error over and over again, since he was not able to make the connection, even if I changed the model field to "actors".

The solution was to turn the `actor = models.ForeignKey` to the following:

```
 actor = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, related_name='movie_list', blank=False)
```

As well as change the `actor_pks` variable to the following:

```
actor_pks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Actor.objects.all(), source='actor', write_only=True, label='Actors', many=True)
```